Two algebraically independent irrational numbers $\alpha,\beta$ s.t. $\alpha^\beta$ is a rational number
Are there two algebraically independent irrational numbers $\alpha,\beta$  s.t. $\alpha^\beta$ is a rational number?

What does “transcendentally independent” mean?

@EmilJeřábek There is no polynomial $F(x,y)$ with integer coefficients with $F(\alpha,\beta)=0$

I suppose you mean nonzero polynomial. Then this is normally called “algebraically independent”.

I also suppose you want this to be unconditionally provable, as it is trivial to construct such examples using Schanuel’s conjecture (e.g., $\alpha=e$ and $\beta=\log2$).

It's true unconditionally. An algebraic curve $P(x,y)=0$ and the analytic curve $(e^t,\frac{ln 2}{t})$ with $t>0$ has only countably many intersections. So there is a value of $t$ that is not on any algebraic curve $P(x,y)=0$ with $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$. Then $\alpha=e^t$ and $\beta=\frac{ln 2}{t}$ are algebraically independent with $\alpha^\beta=2$.

@EmilJeřábek  Thank  you  for your  helpful  comments

@OlegEroshkin  Thank you for  your helpful comment

@EmilJeřábek  I edit to "algebraic independent"

So, for almost all $t$ we have $e^t$ and $\ln 2/t$ are algebraically independent.  Great.  Now exhibit one.

@GeraldEdgar One of Gel'fond's results implies that at least one of $2^{\ln 2}$, $2^{\ln^2 2}$, $2^{\ln^3 2}$ is algebraically independent with $\ln 2$. So you can take $\alpha=2^{\ln^k 2}$ and $\beta=\ln^{-k} 2$ for one of $k=1,2,3$. I don't know if that is sufficiently explicit for you.
